# Can't bypass OpenSSL verification - certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, nokogiri

I am trying to parse an HTTPS XML feed via Nokogiri but I get this OpenSSL error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I can also see the SSL_CERT_FILE:

```
echo $SSL_CERT_FILE
/home/user/certs/cacert.pem
```

This is how I am trying to parse:

```
@feed = "https://example.com/feed1.xml"
doc =  Nokogiri::XML(open(@feed)
```

I tried to bypass the OpenSSL verification, but I still get the same error:

```
doc =  Nokogiri::XML(open(@feed,{ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: try `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` and `Nokogiri::XML(open(@feed))`

Comment: its weird.. now seems it works via this: 'Nokogiri::XML(open(@feed,{ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}))'

Answer (score 7):

This problem usually appears on Windows.

One quick solution is to pass `ssl_verify_mode` to open

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
open(some_url, ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

Another quick one is overriding `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER` in the beginning of your script by doing

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Those who want real solution can try method described on https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Comment: I tried these solutions and got `OpenURI::HTTPError: 500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: @guero64that doesn't sound like it's related to OpenSSL in any way, you get 500 when remote application is running into error so my guess is that url you are trying to hit is just experiencing some problems